# GitKraken access to /disk2/ missing

Tags: filesystem, snap, apparmor, directory-structure

I've installed GitKraken from Snap.

When I try to open a repository from my second disk, I see no `/disk2/` directory in the list of directories under `/`.

I suspect this is caused by application confinement.

How can I access `/disk2/` from GitKraken? And how does this (the thing which causes a directory to be missing) work in general?

Comment: Is /disk2/ an externally mounted disk?  (Snaps run in confinement typically that restrict access to external media / devices / mounts / drives)

Comment: @ThomasWard No, `/disk2` is an internal SATA HDD with Ext4 FS mounted in this directory

Comment: @N0rbert It is not a complete duplicate. My disk is not removable, so that answer does not apply

Comment: @porton N0rbert's suggested duplicate link works the same for me also with non-removeable internal disks.